# How to download pdf in batch using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, selenium-webdriver, download

I have a list of PDF containing urls that I will like to download to disk. The code below downloads just the first PDF in the link and does not continue to execute the last 3 lines for the loop to continue.

```
import time, os
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Downloads")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
profile.set_preference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0")
profile.set_preference("plugin.scan.plid.all", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
notes =["https://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/IMA/05tm9/0/v100_patch_20_detailed_release_notes_November_2015.pdf", "https://download4.boulder.ibm.com/sar/CMA/IMA/092up/0/Guardium_v10_0_p4055_sniffer_update_release_notes.pdf", "https://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/IMA/06nyf/0/SqlGuard_10.0p6022_SecurityUpdate_ReleaseNotes.pdf"]

def download(url)->str:
    driver.get(url)
for note in notes:
    action_process = Process(target=download(note))
    action_process.start()
    action_process.join(timeout=15)
    action_process.terminate()
    os.system('taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F')
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When using `multiprocessing.process`, use the `args` parameter to ensure the called function gets the appropriate values passed in. Also, wait until all the processes are started before calling `join` so the processes will run simultaneously.

If using Windows, you need to add the `freeze_support()` call.

Here is the updated code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
.......

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()  # needed for Windows
    plst = []  # process list
    for note in notes:
        action_process = Process(target=download, args=(note,)) # pass note to process
        action_process.start()
        plst.append(action_process)
        
    for pr in plst:  # wait for all threads to end
       pr.join(timeout=15)
       action_process.terminate()
       
    os.system('taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F') # kill all instances
```